# Delay Bootstrap Carousel 1st transition

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, intervals

I have a carousel with interval of 5 seconds. I want it to delay its start time to 10 seconds ie transition to 2nd image after 10 secs and every image after that every 5 secs.

How can I delay the 1st transition of a carousel?

My code is as follows:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/home/photo_sq7.jpg" alt="image 7 missing" title="Image 7">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/home/photo_sq8.jpg" alt="image 8 missing" title="Image 8">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you'll need to configure and kick off the carousel using javascript, as the attribute configuration does not allow any delay.

Comment: Any idea how i would do that?